# $.tojson not returning form values (but it creates a JSON with form fields )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Not returning form field values

```
var formJSON = $.toJSON($('#form1'));
```

JSP is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ebs.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.json-2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.json-2.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <form id="form1" onclick="validateField()" method="post">
    Text Field 1 : <input id="txt1" name="txt1" type="text" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript is:

```
function validateField() {
  alert('fn called');

  var formJSON = $.toJSON($('#form1'));
  alert('after');
  alert('formJSON' + formJSON);
  alert("method ends here.");
}
```

I am getting:

`form JSON{"length":1,"0":{"txt1":{},"1":{}},"context":{"location":{}},"selector":"#form1"}`

(There is no content for `txt1` field even if we type something there.)

Comment: Sounds like a problem with whatever `$.toJSON` is, or the way you are using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.toJSON()` converts an ordinary Javascript object to JSON.
It does not get values of DOM elements or jQUery objects.

You want [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

Comment: Thank you very much... "serializeArray()" have done the trick. 
I Serialized the from inputs and looped through the array to manually create a json string.